How to use postgres json column in where clause with jooq
I have a postgres database table where one of the many columns is defined as
supported_currencies JSON NOT NULL DEFAULT '["USD"]'::JSON
In the plain SQL I am able to query this table as below
select * from <db_table> where supported_currencies::text in ('["USD"]', '["AUD"]', '["EUR"]')

I am trying to implement this using jooq's feature, I have been exploring and trying a few things have not helped so far.

Is this SQL query really correct? What are you trying to query, rows where there is only exactly one supported currency,  being one of these 3? It looks like you'd rather be querying for rows that support any of the 3 and possibly others, no?

@LukasEder there are many rows where there is only one currency and I am trying to fetch those rows. So, the SQL is correct and you are spot on when you say - "rows where there is only exactly one supported currency" and those are one of USD/AUD/EUR.

I wouldn't convert the query to text first, but just do this instead:
ctx.selectFrom(DB_TABLE)
   .where(DB_TABLE.SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES.in(
       json("[\"USD\"]"), 
       json("[\"AUD\"]"), 
       json("[\"EUR\"]")
   ))
   .fetch();

This is using JSON.json(String) (assuming you're really using JSON, not JSONB, though the answer would be equivalent).
If for some reason you really need to do text comparisons, just cast with jOOQ:
ctx.selectFrom(DB_TABLE)
   .where(DB_TABLE.SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES.cast(CLOB).in(
       "[\"USD\"]", 
       "[\"AUD\"]", 
       "[\"EUR\"]"
   ))
   .fetch();

jOOQ's SQLDataType.CLOB corresponds to PostgreSQL's text type. Or, you can also use SQLDataType.VARCHAR, it shouldn't matter.
